# Create an action in QGIS 2.18 to show image?

Tags: qgis, actions

(Windows 10.1 and QGIS 2.18)

I am trying to create an action for a Shapefile layer that will display an image when any of its three polygons are clicked.

I have added an "image" field to the layer's attribute table, and changed it to "File Name" type, so that each of the layer's polygons has an image associated with it.

I then went to layer properties > actions and created the action as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

But when I tried to click on one of the layer's polygons, I got the following error:

"Unable to run command
open C:/Users/******/Downloads/QGIS-Training-Data-QGIS-Training-Data-v1.0/training_manual_data/school_property_photos/rugby_field.jpg"

I tried to find what I had done wrong, but as far as I could see, I had done everything right. I tried to research but found nothing helpful. I tried to restart both QGIS and my PC but I still got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

From your image, change the `Type` from *Generic* to **Open**.

This should open the url path and if it points to an image file, it should load the file into an image editor.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. Thanks so much anyway!

Comment: @Tookie345 - Do you receive an error? Also, you don't need to change the `File Type` for actions, you can leave it as a _Text Edit_. But the linked post also contains useful answers :)

Comment: I know, the answer on that post fixed my problem for me